# Refresh FirstView from SecondView in Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift

My app is using `Tab Bar Controller` which contains several `View Controller` in different tab. When user open the app, they will firstly enter FirstView. I would like to put some method in SecondView which refresh the FirstView. This is my `FirstViewController.swift`:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
```

I have tried to put

```
FirstViewController().viewDidLoad()
```

in my `SecondViewController.swift`, but this is not working. Is there any better way to refresh the FirstView?

Comment: use delegates for your concept

Comment: or you can access viewcontroller by using `self.tabBarController.viewControllers[index]`

Comment: Why are you calling the `viewDidLoad` method yourself? You shouldn't call it, since it's called by the OS automatically, and only when the view loads.

Comment: @Shamas, I want to refresh the view of my `FirstView`

Comment: You can use post notification for refresh the view. Put viewDidLoad code in post notification method, and call the same method.

Comment: Write a separate function for that. BTW.: `FirstViewController().viewDidLoad()` is not working because `FirstViewController()` creates a new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:-
instead of 0 pass the index of your FirstViewController

```
if let firstVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? FirstViewController {
       firstVC.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way by make a static reference of firstViewController and then through this reference you can call any function

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        static var firstVC : ViewController?
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            print("m on FirstViewController ")
            ViewController.firstVC = self
        }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            print("m on SecondViewController ")
           ViewController.firstVC?.viewDidLoad()
        }

}
```

Comment: I got the error use of undeclared identifier viewcontroller

Comment: You might  have done some naming conventions mistake ..show me your code if  you can

Comment: I have got the solution. Upvote you for the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call viewDidLoad yourself. Its called only once when the view is loaded.

If you want to update the controllers view just before its displayed, you can use viewWillAppear for changing the layout or whatever you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my previous title sound confusing. I have changed my title. What I want to achieve is refresh FirstView from SecondView. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you would want to do that. If the view is not visible it can not be refreshed. The best place you can do this is viewWillAppear. You can use maintain the data states and based on states in viewWillAppear you can refresh the view just before its shown.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're battling it how to tell another view controller that it needs to update its view. For this, you have two potential solutions because effectively, you're determining the best way to communicate between different objects.

**Notifications** are loosely decoupled and tend to be useful for one to many relationships. One object can fire off a notification and one or more objects can be listening for that notification. In your situation, a notification can be broadcast when a certain piece of state has changed in one view controller, and the other view controller can observe that notification so it can be notified when it should change.

**Delegates** are more closely coupled because they're one to one. They are often times implemented by creating a delegate property on an object that conforms to some protocol. Another object then assigns that delegate property to itself and implements the protocol so its implementation will be invoked whenever that function is called on the delegate. In your situation, each view controller could have a delegate property for some protocol(s). The tab bar controller can assign the delegate property to itself and handle the implementations of these functions. Therefore, whenever a change happens and a delegate is invoked, the tab bar controller can take can responsibility of telling which view controllers to update their view.

There are also of course other ways of handling your situation such as updating the view in `viewWillAppear`. This way, whenever a view controller appears on the screen, some code can execute that will update its view.

It ultimately depends on how you're storing application state and the design of your application.